# Design of Google Play Services

Tags: android, design-patterns, google-play-services

wanted to understand more about the design of google play services.

like to use it we need to create an object of GoogleApiClient(see below code) and then we need to add API to which we are interested.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                  this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.build();
```

can any body help me how they built it this whole mechanism. 
this article is help full 
http://wiresareobsolete.com/2016/06/play-services-complexity/
but i want to understand more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the official document - [Overview of Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)

> With Google Play services, your app can take advantage of the latest, Google-powered features such as Maps, Google+, and more, with automatic platform updates distributed as an APK through the Google Play store. This makes it faster for your users to receive updates and easier for you to integrate the newest that Google has to offer.

[image]

> An illustration showing how the Google API Client provides an interface for connecting and making calls to any of the available Google Play services such as Google Play Games and Google Drive.
>
> To get started, you must first install the Google Play services library (revision 15 or higher) for your Android SDK. If you haven't done so already, follow the instructions in Set Up Google Play Services SDK.

Here is a code sample for an activity that implements the callback interfaces and adds them to the Google API Client:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import gms.drive.*;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GoogleApiClient instance
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                                  this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and a connection to Google APIs
        // could not be established. Display an error message, or handle
        // the failure silently

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to use the google play services but all these documents are telling that only. but some how inclined towards knowing the internal details that how they implemented google play services. what data structures they have used. what design considerations they consider etc